# How to convert following method to to 'map' function with return type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I need to replace the following typescript function to `map` and return directly `C[]` array object apart from pass object modify.

```js
function createModelMap(paramA: A, paramB: B,paramD: D, cArray: C[]): void {
  paramA.objects.forEach(
    c => {
      const p = getC(paramB.id, paramD.name);
      if (p) {
        cArray.push(mapC(p.id, p.name));
      }
    }
  );
}
```

need to change this like

```js
function createModelMap(paramA: A, paramB: B ):C[] : undefined {
     paramA.objects.map...   
}
```

Comment: There is no `paramD` passed into your function. I suppose that is a typo?

Comment: oh..yes it should  pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.map`, but this will in turn result in some of the array elements being undefined because you only want to conditionally return when `p` is truthy. Another alternative is to use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), and you just return the array directly:

```
function createModelMap(paramA: A, paramB: B, paramD: D): C[] {
    return paramA.objects.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        const p = getC(paramB.id, paramD.name);
        if (p) {
            acc.push(mapC(p.id, p.name));
        }

        return acc;
    }, [] as C[]);
}
```

Update: it seems like you're not using any values from `paramA.objects`. If that's the case, you can remove the `cur` param:

```
function createModelMap(paramA: A, paramB: B, paramD: D): C[] {
    return paramA.objects.reduce(acc => {
        const p = getC(paramB.id, paramD.name);
        if (p) {
            acc.push(mapC(p.id, p.name));
        }

        return acc;
    }, [] as C[]);
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the code correctly, why is he iterate over param A, when he's not using any params? Wouldn't it be a list containing of the same elements?

Comment: @ChristianMoen I can't explain OP's logic but it is still a legit use-case.

Comment: @ChristianMoen I think OP tried to simplify the code but went too far. It's using `paramD` but there is no such thing passed in. I suspect the real code is more complex but the important thing is that `createModelMap` accepts multiple parameters and uses them to get a value. If that value exists, it adds it to the output, otherwise skips it.

Comment: some type error came , like cannot assign Never;[] ., when i change like this '(acc:curC[], cur)' it was gone

Comment: @uma My bad, the type of the accumulator should have been defined since TypeScript cannot infer its type :) an alternative to your solution would be to manually cast `[] as C[]` in the second argument of the reduce method (see updated answer).